# Geometry of elements with prescribed multiplicity eigenvalues

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, complex-geometry, algebraic-groups, quotient-space

Let us take $G=\operatorname{Gl}(n,\mathbb{C})$ (considered as a linear algebraic group). Let us take $x \in G$: we know that its orbit $\mathcal{O}_x$ under the conjugation action is isomorphic (as algebraic varieties) to $$ G/C_G(x) \cong \mathcal{O}_x $$ via the action map where $C_G(x)$ is the centralizer group. In particular the action map realizes $\mathcal{O}_x$ as the base space of a principal $C_G(x)$ bundle.

I was trying to determine what happens if we take the following more general situation: we take $$n_1+ \dotsb+ n_k=n  $$ and we fix partitions $\lambda_1,\dotsc, \lambda_k$ of $n_1,\dotsc, n_k$ respectively. To each such partition we can associate in a unique way an (uppertriangular) unipotent Jordan matrix, in the canonical way, which we denote $J_{\lambda_i}$.

We put $n_1 \geq  \dotsb \geq n_k$.

We then call $U_{\lambda_1,\dotsc, \lambda_k}$ the set of elements of $\operatorname{Gl}(n,\mathbb{C})$ with $k$ different eigenvalues such that the Jordan form  of the $i$th eigenvalue is given by $J_{\lambda_i}$.

If we denote $$W=\{ (x_i) \in  \mathbb{G}^k_m \mathrel\vert x_i \neq x_j \ ,\ i \neq j\} $$ we have a map
$$W \times Gl(n,\mathbb{C}) \to U_{\lambda_1,\dotsc, \lambda_k} $$ which sends the element $((x_i),g) $ to $g $ applied to the block upper triangular matrix with blocks given by $x_iJ_{\lambda_i}$.

The morphism is surjective and so $ U_{\lambda_1,\dots \lambda_k}$ is constructible: I've tried to prove some of its geometrical properties but I didn't get much. This morphism in general does not seem to be a $C_G(x) $ principal bundle to me: as the fiber can happen to  be bigger than elements of the form $$((x_1, \dotsc, x_k),h) $$ with $h$ in the associated centralizer. Is there a way to change the approach and make this variety a base of a principal $C_G(x)$ bundle?

I was not even able to prove whether this variety is smooth or not (apart from the regular semisimple case $\lambda_i=1$ for example or other degenerate ones). Is there a reference in the literature for this?

EDIT: The question I had in mind more precisely was this. If we take a single orbit, we have that the map $G \to \mathcal{O}_x$ given by the action on $x$ is a principal $C_G(x)$ bundle.

This implies locally on $\mathcal{O}_x$ (even Zariski locally as centraliser in general linear groups are special) that we have section. For each $z \in \mathcal{O}_x$ we have $z \in V$ open  with $\psi_V:V \to G$ such that $\psi(v) \cdot x=v$ with $v \in V$.

Is there a similar morphism for these Lusztig strata?Can we find locally on $U_{\lambda_1, \dots \lambda_k}$ morphisms such as the $\psi_V$? At least to me the biggest problem seems to replace the role of the $x$ in the orbit case with suitable representatives of coniugacy classes in an open $V$.

Comment: I believe what you are describing are called Lusztig strata (or at least are related to them). If I understand correctly, you have fixed a Levi of GL(n) and are looking at the union of conjugacy classes of elements whose semisimple part is a regular element of the center of the Levi, and the nilpotent part lives in a fixed nilpotent orbit of the Levi. I believe they are smooth. See, e.g. Section 3 of Lusztig's 1984 paper "Intersection cohomology complexes..." (which is written for a general reductive group).

Comment: In particular, if $L$ denotes the Levi in question (i.e. block matrices with blocks $(n_1, \ldots , n_k)$) and $\mathcal O$ denotes the corresponding unipotent orbit (unipotent block matrices with Jordan type $\lambda_1, \ldots , \lambda_k$), and $W$ denotes the the regular part of the center of the Levi as in your question, there is a conjugation map $G \times (W\times \mathcal O) \to G$ which surjects onto the locus you describe. This should be a torsor for the normalizer $N_G(L)$.